# Hidden / misplaced in Safari

Tags: html, css

Just figured out that one specific div is hidden in Safari. - For both Mac and iPhone. I have tried searching for the problem, but I can´t figure out where it all goes wrong. It looks like the div `container` is misplaced.

Please see attached images to see how the `container` is moved.

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]
Correctly placed.

**Safari**
[image: Safari]
Misplaced

By adding the following to `container` it gets positioned almost correctly:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

But then the hamburger menu does not work. So I don´t believe it should be set to `position: absolute`, but must be some other code that is either not valid in Safari, or something important has been forgotten.

Not sure how much of the CSS which it needed. It`s pretty long and complicated so please ask and I will provide the code you ask for.

Link: http://www.hitra24.no/

Comment: Looks to me like a `z-index` or bootstrap issue.

Comment: Try validating the HTML

Comment: Tried to validate the HTML, but can´t find any significant error or warning

Comment: Did you try adding `position: relative` to .container? Also, what's the styles for `navbar`? Is it a flex container?

Comment: What styles are on the parent elements? Including `.bareforhamburger`?

Comment: Tried `position: relative` to `.container` and it changed nothing.`.navbar-fixed-top` is `position: fixed`. `header` is set to `position: fixed` and `z-index: 1`. When browsing more on the `.navbar` I found out the problem was `.nav` was set to `overflow: -webkit-paged-y;`. Removing this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was located in my CSS where `.nav` was set to `overflow: -webkit-paged-y;`

By removing this it solved the problem on Safari on both iPhone and Mac.